# How to change content of multiple divs on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am attempting to figure out how to change the content of two different, non-contiguous divs, when a link is clicked.  I have some draft HTML and Javascript, and I suspect missing CSS might be the key to make this work.

Here is the HTML:

```
<ul id="tabs">
<li><a href="#">Link 1</a>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Link 2</a>
</li>
</ul>
<div id="tabs-container">
<div id="content1">Content for link 1. Should display only when Link 1 is clicked.</div>
<div id="content2">Content for link 2. Should display only when Link 2 is clicked.</div>
</div>

<p>Unrelated text is here. Text in this area is static and should display at all times.</p>

<div id="tabs-container-2">
<div id="content1-2">Additional content for link 1. Should display only when Link 1 is clicked.</div>
<div id="content2-2">Additional content for link 2. Should display only when Link 2 is clicked.</div>
</div>
```

---

Here is the Javascript:

```
$(function () {
$('#tabs-container .tabs').hide().eq(0).show();
$('#tabs-container-2 .tabs').hide().eq(0).show();
$('#tabs li').click(function () {
    num = $('#tabs li').index(this);
    $('#tabs-container .tabs').hide().eq(num).show();
    $('#tabs-container-2 .tabs').hide().eq(num).show();
});
});
```

I am a novice at CSS and Javascript. In fact, I deleted my attempt at CSS because it was so poor. Here is the partial jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Fbx_Steve/GbaMx/14/

Hope someone can help. Am I even on the right track?

Comment: Your question is unclear, both content and additional content says it should display when link1 is clicked..

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/GbaMx/20/

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
$(function () {
    $('#tabs-container div').hide().eq(0).show();
    $('#tabs-container-2 div').hide().eq(0).show();

    $('#tabs li').click(function () {
        $('#tabs-container div').hide()
        $('#tabs-container-2 div').hide()
        num = $('#tabs li').index(this);
        $('#tabs-container div').hide().eq(num).show();
        $('#tabs-container-2 div').hide().eq(num).show();
    });
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GbaMx/15/)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're after?

http://jsfiddle.net/GbaMx/16/

I added an id to each link, and when the link is clicked the repective content is toggled.

I grouped them into 2 classes for `.c1 .c2` for content 1 and content 2

Answer (score 0):

Updates JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GbaMx/18/

Your Javascript was totally fine. However, you were trying to reference the `tabs` class, when there were no such classes defined. Thus, I had to update the HTML with ids of `content-x` to have a class of `tabs`.

Comment: YES! Thank you. That's exactly what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**JQUERY CODE:**

```
$(function () {
  $('#tabs-container div').hide();
  $('#tabs-container-2 div').hide();
  $('#tabs li a').on('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    num = $(this).parent().index();
    $('#tabs-container div').eq(num).slideToggle();
    $('#tabs-container-2 div').eq(num).slideToggle();
  });
});
```

**LIVE DEMO:**
http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/GbaMx/22/

There were few things missing in your code, so i have just tuned it a bit.

Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

html

```
<ul id="tabs">
    <li><a id="link1" href="#">Link 1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a id="link2" href="#">Link 2</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<div id="tabs-container">
    <div id="content1" class="contents">Content for link 1. Should display only when Link 1 is clicked.</div>
    <div id="content2" class="contents">Content for link 2. Should display only when Link 2 is clicked.</div>
</div>

<p>Unrelated text is here. Text in this area is static and should display at all times.</p>

<div id="tabs-container-2">
    <div id="content1-2" class="contents">Additional content for link 1. Should display only when Link 1 is clicked.</div>
    <div id="content2-2" class="contents">Additional content for link 2. Should display only when Link 2 is clicked.</div>
</div>
```

javascript

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    // hide tabs
     $('.contents').hide();

    $('#link1').click( function() {
        $('#content1,#content1-2').show();
        return false;
    });
    $('#link2').click( function() {
        $('#content2,#content2-2').show();
        return false;
    });
});
```

see demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Magicianred/BV2kS/1/

Enjoy your code

Answer (score -1):

It works you're only missing a class "tabs" in the content divs:

```
<ul id="tabs">
    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a>

    </li>
</ul>
<div id="tabs-container">
    <div id="content1" class="tabs">Content for link 1. Should display only when Link 1 is clicked.</div>
    <div id="content2" class="tabs">Content for link 2. Should display only when Link 2 is clicked.</div>
</div>
<p>Unrelated text is here. Text in this area is static and should display at all times.</p>
<div id="tabs-container-2">
    <div id="content1-2" class="tabs">Additional content for link 1. Should display only when Link 1 is clicked.</div>
    <div id="content2-2" class="tabs">Additional content for link 2. Should display only when Link 2 is clicked.</div>
</div>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/_wilmer/CHJEQ/)

Comment: i didn't down vote, but maybe becuase somebody already gave the same answer..?

Comment: I might have been late but I did NOT copy anyone else's solution

Comment: Thanks everyone for the quick responses! I can't believe there are so many different ways to do this--and they all work!